# SQL - Duas condições de WHERE diferentes para o mesmo SELECT

Tags: sql, query

Estou desenvolvendo uma query de SQL a qual possuo duas funções WHERE diferentes de acordo com a volta de uma variável.
Tentei algumas alternativas mas nenhuma parece se encaixar, preciso de algo com essa lógica:

```
IF (@show = 1) 
    WHERE d.statusId = ds.id;
ELSE
    WHERE d.statusId != 3;
```

Existe outra alternativa ou algo que atenda minha necessidade?

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terá que avaliar a variável `@show` dentro do próprio `WHERE`:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        xxx d
INNER JOIN  yyy ds ON ds.id_xxx = d.id
WHERE       d.statusId =  (CASE WHEN @show = 1  THEN ds.id  END)
        OR  d.statusId <> (CASE WHEN @show <> 1 THEN 3      END)
```

Não sabendo a estrutura das tabelas e a informação que cada uma contém, é um "tiro no escuro", mas em princípio funciona.

Comment: Funcionou! Muitissímo obrigado :D

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o `OR`:

```
WHERE (@show = 1 AND d.statusId = ds.id)
   OR d.statusId != 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu consegui compreender isso deve resolver seu problema:

```
set @show = 1;

SELECT * FROM banco.tabela
where if(@show = 1,d.statusId = ds.id,d.statusId != 3);
```

"Esse é um exemplo funcional ai voce adapta as suas nescessidades"

Este aqui é o link da documentação do mysql caso queira dar uma estudada.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Só atente que o `if` não funciona em todos os `SGBDs`